# How to fill an array in a class JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

So I am having issues with a program i am trying to create. I cannot put in data into the array `int[] serviceCode` without the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Job_18028094.<init>(Job_18028094.java:24)
    at BMAS_Main_18028094.main(BMAS_Main_18028094.java:76)
```

Here is the relevant section of my code.

From my Main:

```
String[] tempRecords = fileScan.nextLine().split(",");
jobList[loopCount] = new Job_18028094(tempRecords);
```

From my class 'Job':

```
private int[] serviceCode;

public Job_18028094(String[] tempRecords) {
    serviceCode[0] = Integer.parseInt(tempRecords[6]);
}
```

To clear things up, there is data held in `tempRecords[6]` as `String` (but is all numbers) and have been using `Integer#parseInt` prior to convert them. I researched what the error means and have turned up with it meaning that the variable is a 'null' value, but I am unsure as to how to change this or just over write it with the data in tempRecords.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: You never initialized serviceCode

Comment: What are you trying to do in your constructor? In what you wrote, you're trying to put the 7th element of `tempRecords` in the 1st cell of `serviceCode` (which does not exist yet because the whole array is not initialized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize this `array` before use it.

```
 private int[] serviceCode; // else serviceCode is null
```

You can use

```
 private int[] serviceCode=new int[5];
```

If you are not sure about the `length` of the `array`. Use `List`

```
 List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The NullPointerException is thrown , because the ServiceCode array is not initialized. Arrays are static objects and need to be initialized prior any use. Also, you should provide the size of this array before using it ! try to pass a "size" parameter to Job_18028094 constructor. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply declare an array using the statement `private int[] serviceCode;`, you are telling to the compiler that a variable named **serviceCode** will hold an array of integers. At this point of time, compile is not informed about how many integers that the array will be holding. So the actual memory allocation to hold the integers will not happen by this time.

To start putting integers into an array, the corresponding memory allocation should have happened already. Compiler will take care of doing this memory allocation only when you initialize the array using the following statement.

```
int[] serviceCode = new int[5]
```

After the above initialization, memory allocation will be completed for the array to hold 5 integers and the array will be filled with the default values for the integers (which is '0'). Now you can start putting different values into the array.

In your case, since you have not initialized the array, memory allocation did not happen which caused the NullPointerException to be thrown when you tried accessing the array.